# Network configuration for linux server

Tags: networking, linux-networking

I had some troubles with a Linux server after being restarted.
I can log to the machine but I cannot remotely access this machine via ssh client: `ssh -v -v -v root@IP` gives me `connect to host IP port 22: No route to host`.
From this machine when I do ping a domain like google.com I get this :`unknown host` and when I try to ping any IP address I get `network is unreachable`.
This apparently a network configuration issue, so a took a look to my `/etc/resolv.conf` file and every thing seems to be ok:

```
nameserver <internal DNS server IP>
domain <FQDN>
search <FQDN>
```

and `ifconfig` commad gives me:

```
  eth0 Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 18:a9:05:3f:7a:62  
  inet Adresse:MY-IP  Bcast:192.xxx.x.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
  inet6-Adresse: fe80::1aa9:5ff:fe3f:7a62/64 
  UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
  RX packets:27983252 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
  TX packets:111252815 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
  RX bytes:3051411934 (2.8 GiB)  TX bytes:159983260344 (148.9 GiB)
  Interrupt:18 Speicher:f8000000-f8012800
```

but the problem is that eth0 is down:

```
cat /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate
```

I tried to activate it: `ifconfig eth0 up` but it didnt work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Is the eth cable ok?

Comment: to be honest with you I think this is a cabe issue but I cannot check since I have no knowledges in cable issues, but I want to figure out if this is a cable problem with terminal commands

Comment: Try changing it with another one that works. Maybe buy a new one since they'll probably cost not more that a couple of USD

Comment: This is not the problem, the problem is I dont know where to plug the cable, the server have many cables :(

Comment: Ah ok.. got you. Then, if you can, issue a ping command that will go continuosly, and try unplugging the cable from one port and one at a time try all the eth ports. If ping replies you found it! Most probable you have plugged it in the wrong port.

Comment: I didn't understand you very well but I tried to check whether network cable is plugged in with `ip link show` command is that enough?

Comment: Do you have physical access to the server?

Comment: yes I do hav ...

Comment: Right. Open the console, type in ping google.com, Then go behind the server. Remove the the eth cable from the current port and plug it into the next eth port. wait 10 seconds and see if ping is replying. If not then repeat the operation until you finished all of the eth ports. It's just to understand if you have plugged the cable in the right ethernet port.

Comment: I tried this even with an other cable of another server but it is not working

Comment: I don't see the output from `ip link show`. There should be LEDs on both the network interface and on the switch, which should turn on when the cable is plugged in. If the LEDs do not turn on, it means there is no link. Please include the full IP addresses. There has been reports of cases where people have mistakenly tried to configure `192.168.0.0/8`, which could have happened in your case. Also it'll be a bit easier for more people to help if you post output in English. You can type `export LANG=C` to switch to English for the current shell.

Comment: `ifconfig` is deprecated.  You can use `ip monitor link` to monitor link states: If you unplug/replug a cable, you will get output of which interface was unplugged/plugged (watch out for NO-CARRIER).  Alternatively, `cat /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier` will tell you if a cable is plugged.

Comment: I guess there's an internal IP configured on the interface:
Bcast:192.xxx.x.255
If you get a "network is unreachable", there's probably a default route to the gateway missing. What does `ip r ls` say?

Answer (score 0):

The message you are getting is the clue: "No route to host".  Check the routing table for the host you are doing the ssh *from*.  The command to do that is:

```
ip route show
```

and the output will look something like this:

```
10.200.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.200.2.7 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link 
default via 10.200.2.1 dev eth0
```

Because you are getting a "no route to host" message, that means:
1) the IP you are trying to ssh to is not on your local network, and
2) you don't have a default route.  That is to say, the IP didn't match any of the routes in your routing table.

Do you have a router?  If so, you should have a default route to that router.  To add one enter a command similar to this:

```
ip route add default via 10.200.2.1
```

You will want to make these changes permanent (that is survive rebooting your system) but since you didn't mention your operating system distribution, I can't help you there.